# Spelling Quiz- Event Listener for Correct and Incorrect Button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, addeventlistener

I'm currently trying to create a spelling quiz as part of a project website using HTML, CSS and JScript.

The concept is: the user is shown a word with two letters missing (shown by the underscores). They then select which answer is right (the three button options) and an alert message should come back on the window to say if they are correct or incorrect.

My idea behind the code I wrote so far was to have an event listener on the button that when clicked would trigger the alert either saying correct or incorrect if I have programmed it to be so.

My code isn't working, could anyone help me?

```js
var aChoice = document.getElementById("S1");

aChoice.addEventLister("Click", C1)
function C1 ()
{
  alert("Correct");
}
```

```css
#QuizBod {
    background-color: #ffff80;
}

#QTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFBF00;
}

#S1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <!--Mobile Compatibility-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--Style Sheet, Google Font Link, Page Title-->
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Langar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Spelling Test</title>
    </head>

    <body id="QuizBod">
        <h2 id="QTitle">Spelling Quiz</h2>

        <p id="MQ1">C h _ _ r</p>
        <label class ="Albl">Answer:
            <button id="S1">a i</button>
            <button id="S1">i a</button>
            <button id="S1">e i</button>
        </label> 


    <script src="SpellTest.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

(More code I was intending to write on Javascript here for logic purposes.)

```js
var bChoice = document.getElementById("S2");

bChoice.addEventLister("Click", C2)
function C2 ()
{
  alert("Incorrect");
}

var cChoice = document.getElementById("S3");

cChoice.addEventLister("Click", C2)
function C2 ()
{
  alert("Incorrect");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You cannot have more than one `id="S1"`! Since the `id` attribute is unique for the entire `html` document. In your case, it is better to use the `class`. Since there may be more buttons with answer options, like this:

```
<label class="Albl">Answer:
   <button class="btn">a i</button>
   <button class="btn">i a</button>
   <button class="btn">e i</button>
</label>
```

2.Now on js ... I corrected your code. Also, you need to change the method of accessing elements (buttons). Like this:

```
var aChoice = document.querySelector(".btn");
```

3.Now everything is ready, but not completely! You need the logic for determining the correctness of the choice of the option by buttons.

```js
var aChoice = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

aChoice.forEach(function(aChoice_current, index) {
  aChoice_current.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (index == 0) {
      console.log('The answer is correct! :)');
    } else {
      console.log('The answer is not correct! :(');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#QuizBod {
    background-color: #ffff80;
}

#QTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFBF00;
}

.btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <!--Mobile Compatibility-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--Style Sheet, Google Font Link, Page Title-->
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Langar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Spelling Test</title>
    </head>

    <body id="QuizBod">
        <h2 id="QTitle">Spelling Quiz</h2>

        <p id="MQ1">C h _ _ r</p>
        <label class="Albl">Answer:
            <button class="btn">a i</button>
            <button class="btn">i a</button>
            <button class="btn">e i</button>
        </label> 


    <script src="SpellTest.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that advice! My only issue is, the reason I as going to give each button a separate ID s1, s2 etc. is because I need to be able say a certain button is right. If I class all the buttons as just "btn" how would be able to program in javascript that one of those specific buttons is correct?

Comment: var bChoice = document.getElementById("S2");

bChoice.addEventLister("Click", C2)
function C2 ()
{
  alert("Incorrect");
}

var cChoice = document.getElementById("S3");

cChoice.addEventLister("Click", C2)
function C2 ()
{
  alert("Incorrect");
}

Comment: @RachelF, To make each `btn` class unique, you need to use the `forEach()` method - this is a more competent approach to solving your problem.

Comment: @RachelF, I modified the code, and now you will see the text of each clicked button, and the index of the button. In this way, you can refuse to use `id`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean on how I could reuse the id? Could you perhaps give me an example in this instance 'ai' is the correct button to be clicked for the chair spelling question?

Comment: @RachelF, I have updated the answer. Test code by running the snippet and look at the console messages.

Comment: @RachelF, Have you checked the code I updated? Is this the result you wanted?